# From nodal admittance matrix to an electrical circuit

Tags: circuit-analysis, ltspice, frequency

Bear with me on this one.
I have a one port circuit whose impedance has been measured from input port 'x' (the circuit is a wide complicated electrical circuit run in LTspice)

[image: One-port network with a single impedance, Z]

I was able to make it a two port circuit and extract the nodal admittance matrix of the form using LTspice (excite one port while short circuit the other and vice-versa ok?)

$$Y = \begin{bmatrix} Y_{11} & Y_{12} \\ Y_{21} & Y_{22}\end{bmatrix}$$

Now we all know that I can deduce the equivalent circuit of the now two port circuit (input nodes named 'x' and 'y') to look like this

[image: Two-port pi network with impedances Z1 (left), Z2 (middle), and Z3 (right)]

where

$$Z_1 = \frac 1 {Y_{11}+Y_{12}}$$

$$Z_2 = -Y_{12} = -Y_{21}$$

$$Z_3 = \frac 1 {Y_{21}+Y_{22}}$$

The two ports circuit's impedance equals: Z = 1/(1/(Z2+Z3)+1/Z1) which eventually is the same as the one seen in the first figure.

However when I compare the two impedances (of the first figure) and the one recomputed using the previous expression I have a problem in the phase (I have a -1 that I don't know where it's coming from?) as seen below:

[image]

This has taken a me while so feedback will be very much appreciated.

Comment: The units of your formula for Z2 look wrong. You have impedance = negative admittance. Are you sure that's right?

Comment: @AdamHaun Yes it is, check this paper https://ieeexplore.ieee.org/abstract/document/252667?casa_token=KmqpNfaFBSwAAAAA:wDRLRlxwzPraH3Rfo19EKExMUIStVioLn9rp4Kdui4g9FtVQZLArH3ebrLUL85S0F2SQmNmP_xHK

Comment: The paper is not free and costs $33 USD.  I made a snarky comment earlier but I guess the point went over the moderator's head.

Comment: @SteKulov I found your comment unnecessary. There are other ways to find the paper.

Comment: Oh, OK.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I can't access the paper you linked to, but according to Wikipedia and [other sources](https://eng.libretexts.org/Bookshelves/Electrical_Engineering/Electronics/Book%3A_Fundamentals_of_Microwave_and_RF_Design_(Steer)/07%3A_Microwave_Network_Analysis/7.02%3A_Two-Port_Networks), there's an error in your formula. The pi equivalent circuit for your admittance parameters is:

[image: Pi network of admittances]

The equivalent impedances should be the inverse of the admittances, but your \$Z_2\$ formula is \$Z_2 = -Y_{12}\$, which is still an admittance. Try using:

$$Z_2 = \frac 1 {-Y_{12}}$$

Comment: Yes you are right about that, I made a mistake writing the question, but my script is still correct